# Change the default caret cursor color in a textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the default grey colored caret cursor to black for the following textarea code

```
<div class = "">
    <form:textarea class="textarea-large span12" path=" " placeholder="Type Here" " />
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add `style="cursor: pointer"` to the textarea attributes (e.g. before class=...)

I think that's "caret" - a full list of pointers is available [on the web](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a custom cursor-file and use that for textareas:

```
textarea {
    cursor: url(cursor.cur);
}
```

take a look at [this great article](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/) about this topic - it's about 5 years old, but still up to date.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you're trying to change the mouse cursor.  Usually for textarea below css is common.

```
textarea
{
cursor:text;
}
```

I think there is no option to change the color of the mouse.  For more option check [W3C School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=crosshair).